# Cannot convert undefined or null to object Problem - Using API balldontlie

Tags: jquery, api, object

When an API has null or undefined key values, can I somehow change the values or what can I do, when these values occur? I'm using JQuery to get the data from the balldontlie API.

I tried logging the output the object gives me and I got undefined as type and I tried solving the problem by checking if the value is null or undefined than something should happen. I tried changing the values but with no luck.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are getting and what you want it transformed too

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.